# NeoVim: Show cursorline only in active panes without messing other plugin-related text inputs

Tags: lua, neovim

Currently I'm using the following vim autocmd to show the cursorline only in active pane (i.e. current buffer) as follows.

```
augroup CursorLine
    au!
    au VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * setlocal cursorline
    au WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
augroup END
```

But it's also showing cursorline in plugin-related-buffers since it's forcing to set cursorline in current-buffer with `WinEnter`. For example, there's cursorline in search box of Telescope Find Files as shown in the picture below.

[Cursorline in text input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keAFs.jpg)

I tried to hide cursorline just only for Telescope plugin with `‌autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter Telescope* setlocal nocursorline` and it doesn't work, cursorline is still appearing.

*So, is there any workaround to avoid this issue?*

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: 1.** I just tried an experiment `autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter NvimTree* setlocal nocursorline` and cursorline in NvimTree plugin has disappeared as I wanted. *So, why isn't this working in Telescope?? Or do we need to address the issue in different way??*

**Edit 2.** I just tried using `TelescopePrompt` instead of `Telescope` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FileType` in your autocmd to disable `cursorline` for Telescope plugin :

```
au FileType Telescope setlocal nocursorline
```

You can also use the same configuration for your other plugin-related-buffers.

Comment: I just did as you mentioned above and it worked. I just needed to change the file type to `TelescopePrompt*` instead of just `Telescope`. So the autocmd will be: `au FileType TelescopePrompt* setlocal nocursorline`. Thank you very much for the solution bruh.